# Html страничка полностью во весь экран мобильного устройства, как реализовать?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть проект, в нём нет адаптивной версии и нужно сделать чтобы по умолчанию сайт на мобильных открывался полностью во весь экран, хоть текст и кнопки нужно будет зумировать и тд но вот нужно сделать так.

Выставляю стили для body, но открываю на мобильном и сайт открывается не так как надо, ниже прикреплю 2 картинки как нужно и как сейчас.

```css
html {
  min-width: 1280px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 1280px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>default title</title>
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
  <link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--<![endif]-->

  <meta property="og:title" content="" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="" />
  <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
  <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
  <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
  <meta property="twitter:description" content="" />
  <link rel="image_src" href="" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:100,200,300,400,500,600,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
```

Изображения, как сейчас открывается и как нужно, чтобы открывался, устройство iphone 5s

PS: Правильное отображение можно получить только зумированием сайта

[image: как открывается сейчас]

[image: как нужно чтобы открывался!]

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
` в `head` добавьте

Comment: используйте медиа запросы

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev первым делом было добавлено, но не помогает

Comment: @SergeyArchipov каким именно образом? На каждое устройство свой медиа запрос?

Comment: @msupreme, https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @SergeyArchipov ну мне кажется что мне медиа запросы не нужны, у меня просто какой-то либо баг, либо я где-то что-то упускаю в стилях body или html

Comment: Покажите всю разметку тега `head`

Comment: @VasiliyRusin приложил в саму тему код head

Comment: ну у вас же `html { min-width: 1280px; }`

Comment: @diproart а нужно? Я поэтому и спрашиваю, первый раз с таким пожеланием столкнулся)

я пытался по разному html { min-width: 100%; } и body { min-width: 1280px; }

Там просто блок с контентом 1280px

Comment: если мы указали min-width: 1280px, то так и будет (в современных браузерах), если сайт не зуммируется - значит внутри контента есть блоки с фиксированной шириной, таблицами или "большими" картинками "без адаптивности". лучше всего использовать   "инструмент разработчика chrome"  - включите отображение "layer borders" и всё увидите сами.

Comment: @diproart то есть если убрать фиксированную ширину блоков то должно стать как нужно?

Comment: @diproart но вот собственно главная страница сайта имеет внутри контент блоки с фиксированной шириной но отображается на устройствах как нужно https://bookscriptor.ru/

Comment: ну и хорошо, это же то, что хотелось? вы же убрали min-width. Сайт зуммируется как надо, 100% ширины устройства.

Comment: @diproart в том и дело что я не могу понять чем вот пример который был выше отличается от моей верстки вот тестовая ссылка на мою врестку http://uma199pa.beget.tech/

Comment: @diproart буду очень благодарен если поможете понять этот момент

Comment: @diproart Вообщем разобрался, спасибо, как раз ваши комментарии помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Используете медиа-запросы.
Советую использовать Grid (Адаптивная сетка). Ссылка: [тык](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

```css
  // Ландшафтный экран телефоны
  @media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
 
  // От ландшафтного экрана телефона до потретного планшета
  @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
 
  // От портретного планшета до ландшафтного экрана и настольных дисплеев
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
 
  // Большой дисплей
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```